# Senegal visa on Angolan passport

Tags: visas, senegal

According to various sources, Senegal has totally scrapped its visa requirements. Is this applicable to ALL countries though? I have an Angolan passport. If I look at the [visa policy for Senegal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Senegal), it shows Angola as grey though, but doesn't say what happens if you fall in the grey zone. It then adds: "Passengers with proof of accommodation can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 30 days."  (which got me wondering if this would then apply to my nationality).

Does anyone know whether I can obtain a visa on arrival at Dakar airport with the Angolan passport? (Note: there doesn't seem to be a consulate where I reside and the evisa has been scrapped).

Comment: The Wiki map shows *green* for those who can enter visa free, and *grey* for those who require a visa.

Comment: @Giorgio but is it a visa you get on arrival or not??

Comment: Not according to Timatic, the system used by airlines. The links to the official online visa systems seems to be broken. If you'll say where you're located, I'll look for a consulate, or try to find a visa service.  (And it appears that all travellers there require a yellow fever vaccination, btw.)

Comment: @Giorgio I currently reside in Kinshasa, DRC. I do have yellow vaccination.

Comment: I've put in the info in an answer. After you go through the visa process, you can always come back here and add your own answer (process, cost, ease, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the timatic response @Giorgio. Doesn't the following line mean I can obtain the visa on arrival though?  ===>  "Passengers with an official invitation letter issued by a Senegalese Authority to participants of international events or a proof of accommodation can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 30 days."

Comment: It still says visa is required, so I would check with the Consulate General in Kinshasa to be sure before attempting to board a flight.

Answer (score 3):

Courtesy of [Emirates web site sharing of the Timatic tool](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx), the information used by airlines for passenger entry requirements, you would require a visa ([Angola passport holder, living in DR Congo](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=AO&NV=Angola&AC=CD&AV=Congo%2C%20Democratic%20Repulic%20of%20the&DC=SN&DV=Senegal&h=efd6f1a575778d1eed17e6f99c19032269749)):

> **Destination - Senegal (SN)**
>
> **Passport**
>   Passport required.
>
> **Document Validity**:
>   Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for a minimum of 3 months from the arrival date.
>   **Visa**
>   Visa required.
>
> **Visa Issuance**:
>   Passengers with an official invitation letter issued by a Senegalese Authority to participants of international events or a proof of accommodation can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 30 days.
>   **Warning:**
>   Visa required visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.

There is a Senegalese Honorary Consulate General in Kinshasa:

4270 bis av. Du Progrès, Barumbu
Kinshasa
TELEPHONE(+243) 999 993 101

According to [Embassy Pages](https://www.embassypages.com/missions/embassy16323/), it is the only Senegalese representation in Democratic Republic Congo.